# Real Time Interaction on Web Page

Tags: javascript, php, web, web-applications, embedded

Background: I have a microcontroller ESP8266 that enable connexion through TCP/IP, UDP or even HTTP stack using WiFi. A button is connected to this microcontroller and trigger event on touch. I send that information (now in UDP for test) towards a computer which runs an HTML carousel (web page). I would like to create the interaction between the button and the web page in real-time. I found that a simple HTML/CSS/JS web page doesn't allow to read UDP socket so I install a web server on the computer to use PHP.

NB: Real-time means direct interaction (inferior to 30 ms up to 100 ms) but should be ok in the actual data flow.

Problem: I struggle on the Web implementation. I found appropriate carousel in HTML/CSS/JS. I already received some UDP packet in a PHP file but I don't know how can I perform a real-time interaction (trigger image change in the carousel). I read about Ajax but it seems to be at client-side. I have in fact no background in Web application design.

I would like to know if in fact, it is possible and if yes basic information to start working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't completely understand your microcontroller setup I can tell you that it is defiantly possible to change html elements and values in real-time. The place where I work uses Angular.js and it has a handy "scope" variable that is directly linked to the HTML. So, if the value in the code changes it will change on the website as well (without reloading the page). Its relatively simple to begin with but check out demos or something first, maybe I understand the question wrong.

https://angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible. Your two options are polling and websockets. If your backend is PHP, I'd start by writing some JavaScript to to poll the server at a given URL every 200 ms. Your PHP code handing that URL endpoint would then read a value from a data store somewhere, let's say a cache key in memcached.

1. Press button
2. UDP message sent
3. PHP code receives UDP message and sets value in cache key
4. When your polling code runs next it will receive the updated data which you can then display on your webpage.

This is a really basic (and inefficient) setup, but it's simple and should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

We struggled with this same problem and eventually used NGINX and the PUSH module.

It allows a Post message to the server (NGINX) to be pushed to displayed web pages on the browser.

In our setup the controller sends a POST,containing JSON data, to a small linux board running NGINX. NGINX then sends this to any subscribers. The web page contains a couple of lines of js code to subscribe to the feed. When the JSON arrives at the page, it fires the js receiving code, and we update the displayed fields in the webpage. The setup is quite responsive, without measuring the delay, it seems to be within 60ms.